# Advanced Custom Fields Auto Populating Field Values For Nested Repeater FIelds

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

So we have configured a filter to automatically populate ACF Fields from a custom post type and we have this working for a top-level flexible content block. However, we don't seem to be able to do the same for a nested flexible content. Block.

So in the example below, block 1 etc will be it's own flexible content field with it's set of fields. I'm hoping someone has someone can help. Thanks for your time everyone

```
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=driving_for_work_policy_v2', 'add_starting_repeaterv2', 10, 3);
  function  add_starting_repeaterv2($value, $post_id, $field) {
    if ($value !== NULL) {
      // $value will only be NULL on a new post
      return $value;
    }
    // add default layouts
    $value = array(
      array(
        //add block 1 This is also flexible with its own set of fields we need to auto populate. How do we reference this as a flex field and not just as a field of the parent. 
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'policy_statement',
      ),
      
      array(
        //add block 2  
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'the_driver' 
      ),
      array(
        //add block 3
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'the_vehicle'
      ),
      array(
        //add block 4  
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'the_journey'
      ),
      array(
        //add block 5 
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'grey_fleet_drivers'
      ),
      array(
        //add block 6  
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'additional_section'
      ),
    );
    return $value;
}
```